# Create Training and Test Dataset in R

Tags: r, subset, training-data

I want to create training and test data from `mydata`, which has 2673 observations and 23 variables. However, I am not able to create the test set just by simply subtracting the training data.

```
dim(mydata)
## [1] 2673   23
set.seed(1)
train = mydata[sample(1:nrow(mydata), 1000, replace=FALSE), ]
dim(train)
## [1] 1000   23
```

When I run the following, I got 19 warnings and the the result has 20,062 observations:

```
test = mydata[!train, ]
## There were 19 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
dim(test)
## [1] 20062    23
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Relevant here http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/54964

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution involves storing the sampled indices in a separate named vector.

```
train_idx <- sample(1:nrow(mydata),1000,replace=FALSE)
train <- mydata[train_idx,] # select all these rows
test <- mydata[-train_idx,] # select all but these rows
```

Also, knowing that a `data.frame`'s `row.names` attribute must consist of unique values,
you may also set e.g.

```
test <- mydata[!(row.names(mydata) %in% row.names(train)), ]
```

But the second solution is 2x slower on `mydata <- data.frame(a=1:100000, b=rep(letters, len=100000))`, as measured by `microbenchmark()`.

Comment: Thanks! I still need to set the seed before creating `train_idx` correct?

Comment: If you wish to obtain reproducible results, call `set.seed(some_number)` before `sample()`. If that's not important to you, leave the seed as-is (it is automatically set according to system time + some other info).